# jsTree.js library - How to catch the contextmenu create event so i can change its behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to catch the create event from the jsTree context menu so i can do whatever i want after i right-click on the node and choose "Create".
[image]

For example i want to enter into another page after i click "Create" and to disable the default behavior of the create button.

Which event i should use from the library documentation ?

I'm trying something like this to try catch the event but it doesnt work.

```
 $(".jstree").bind("create.jstree", function(event,data)
   {
            alert("hello");
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for jstree.js js library inside your code. If you are using CDN link, than download the js file in your system and search for the following line:

> $.jstree.defaults.contextmenu = {

Inside this function you get code like:

```
items : function (o, cb) { // Could be an object directly
            return {
                "create" : {}
                // This is the create function block which is called when create is clicked. You can change it accordingly.
```

Comment: Yes, I have change the options according to me by this trick :)